# property of class doesnt restrict the attribute

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, attributes

So i made a class and want, that attribute hp stays always between 0 and maxhp
In theory making hp a property should give me the wished result: Somehow it doesnt work though.

Is there way to link attributes for and back? So i have stored the position of the unit class object. At 2 places, once the attribute position which contains a [x,y] array and the other time its stored in 2 attributes x and y and each contains a int. 
Changing self.x or self.y should changes self.position and the other way around too.

```
 class units(object):

    def __init__(self,typus, position, stats):
        self.type = typus

        #they should be linked both directions
        self.position = position
        self.x = self.position[0]
        self.y = self.position[1]

        self.attack = stats[0]
        self.defense = stats[1]
        self.maxhp = stats[2]
        self.hp = self.maxhp

    def __repr__(self):
        text = "This a %s at position [%s,%s].\n  Attack: %s \n Defense: %s \n Hp : %s/%s \n "  \
               % (self.type,self.position[0],self.position[1],  self.attack, self.defense, self.hp, self.maxhp)
        return text


    # hp set to always be in between 0 and maxhp
    @property
    def hp(self):
        return self.__hp

    @hp.setter
    def hp(self, hp):
        if hp < 0:
            self.__hp = 0
        if hp > self.maxhp:
            self.__hp = self.maxhp
        else:
            self.__hp = hp

    def takedmg(self,dmg):
        self.hp -= max(dmg-self.defense, 0)
        if self.hp <= 0:
            self.alive = False
        return self.hp



p = units("peasant", [1,1],  [2,0,30])
p.takedmg(100)
print (p.hp)     # it should be 0!
```

Comment: And along with the changes given in my answer, consider using [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for the long `__repr__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `__init__`, the line `self.hp = self.maxhp` should be `self.__hp = self.maxhp`. That way it's only set/get in the `@property` methods.

You would handle `postion`, `x` and `y` the same way as you've done for `hp`. Use `_postion`, `_x` and `_y` internally to correspond to the values in the getters and setters; and set all of the `_prop` values in the setters of each. Using `position` as a an example:

```
@property
def position(self):
    return self._position

@position.setter
def position(self, position):
    self._position = position  # do checking before this if needed
    self._x = position[0]
    self._y = position[1]
```

Similarly for `x` and `y`, though I think you should only do it via `position`:

```
@property
def x(self):
    return self._x

@x.setter
def x(self, x):
    self._x = x
    # self._y remains unchanged
    self._position[0] = x
```

Btw, the `hp` setter can be re-written as follows:

```
@hp.setter
def hp(self, hp):
    self.__hp = max(0, min(hp, self.maxhp))
```

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot. The rewrinting of hp: I really like itsince there actually lots of attributes that need a similiar behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I use a similar approach to implement such behaviour. It's also the _pythonic_ way to do it - so almost everyone does. One thing to add, do you necessarily need the double-underscore name-mangling for `self.__hp` vs `self._hp` which is just considered private? That's only really needed if you don't want a sub-class's implementation to interfere with yours.

Comment: Well that was the way showed when i googeled how to use property. So no doesnt make any difference. One small question "do checking before this if needed" what do you mean with that?

Comment: "do checking before this if needed" for `position` such as not allowing negative values (if appropriate) or not allowing `x` and `y` values which are out of bounds of the map/grid.

Answer (score 1):

Another problem is in `hp.setter`. The second `if` statement should be replaced with `elif` because when `hp` is less than 0, `self.__hp` is set to 0 in first `if` and then, without `elif`, it is set to a negative value in `else`:

```
@hp.setter
def hp(self, hp):
    if hp < 0:
        self.__hp = 0
    elif hp > self.maxhp:
        self.__hp = self.maxhp
    else:
        self.__hp = hp
```

Comment: That's not really a problem, unless `maxhp` can be negative. Putting it as an `elif` _is_ better/clearer/optimised but it's definitely not the problem.

Comment: That's a real problem in the example code. When hp is <0 self.__hp is set to 0 in first if, then, without elif, is it set to negative value in else.

Comment: Good point, missed that. Fortunately, the `hp.setter` I put in my answer doesn't have that bug. I've edited your answer and added your explanation (and undone my -ve vote). _Though_ that wasn't the OP's question wrt setting dependent values.